# ExoPlayer not playing onViewRecycled when I back to the previous view ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, exoplayer2.x, android-viewpager2

I am working with ViewPager2 with recycler view adapter and setup following things as shown below

When i swipe the screen and change the index its works fine for new index but when I go to previous index it wont play any video whY? any suggestions??

RecylcerViewAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull VideoPlayerViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    holder.pausePlayer();
    holder.releasePlayer();
}

@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull VideoPlayerViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    holder.startPlayer();
}

  @Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull VideoPlayerViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    holder.startPlayer();
}


 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VideoPlayerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setExoplayer(getItem(position).getUrl());
}
```

***ViewHolderr.java***

```
  public void startPlayer() {
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    player.getPlaybackState();
}

public void pausePlayer() {
 
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    player.getPlaybackState();
}


public void setExoplayer(String url) {
    player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(itemView.getContext()).build();
    player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
    dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(itemView.getContext(),"exo-player");
    mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));
    player.prepare(mediaSource);
    playerView.setPlayer(player); //need to transfer
    player.seekTo(playbackPosition);
    player.addListener(this);
}

public void releasePlayer() {
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    player.release();
    player.stop(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set Exoplayer when view is attached like this

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull VideoPlayerViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    holder.setExoplayer();
    holder.startPlayer();
}
```